# Saving Many to Many in MVC asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net, entity-framework-6

i read a lot about MVC. But until now there is no clear answer how to handle many to many relation cause many of these tutorial result have the same bug.
I am using Database first approach, my application should add Users and while adding users I should have a list from the roles and i could add these roles to this user or the opposite i could have roles with list of user and edit and as we know when I add the data base  with breaking table to ado.net so the relation will be many to many.
I have successfully add list of the roles but when i press save i got the exception of null reference.
And this is my code :

First the custom view :

```
namespace UserMangment.ViewModel
{
    public class RolesViewMode
    {
        public tab_OnlineUsers OnlineUsers { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllRolesnames { get; set; }

        private List<string> _selectedRolesname;


        public List<string> SelectedRoleTags
        {
            get
            {
                if (_selectedRolesname == null)
                {
                    _selectedRolesname = OnlineUsers.tab_OnlineRoles.Select(m => m.Id).ToList();
                }
                return _selectedRolesname;
            }
            set { _selectedRolesname = value; }
        }


    }
}
```

Then the controller :

```
namespace ELVIRA_UserMangment.Controllers
{
    public class OnlineUsersController : Controller
    {
        private Entities db = new Entities();

        // GET: OnlineUsers
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.tab_OnlineUsers.ToList());
        }

        // GET: OnlineUsers/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            tab_OnlineUsers tab_OnlineUsers = db.tab_OnlineUsers.Find(id);
            if (tab_OnlineUsers == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tab_OnlineUsers);
        }

        // GET: OnlineUsers/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var RolesViewmode = new RolesViewMode
            {
                OnlineUsers = db.tab_OnlineUsers.Create(),
            };
            if (RolesViewmode.OnlineUsers == null)
                return HttpNotFound();

            var allrolles = db.tab_OnlineRoles.ToList();
            RolesViewmode.AllRolesnames = allrolles.Select(o => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = o.Name,
                Value = o.Id.ToString()
            });
            return View(RolesViewmode);
        }

        // POST: OnlineUsers/Create
        // Aktivieren Sie zum Schutz vor übermäßigem Senden von Angriffen die spezifischen Eigenschaften, mit denen eine Bindung erfolgen soll. Weitere Informationen 
        // finden Sie unter http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Email,EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEndDateUtc,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount,UserName")] RolesViewMode tab_OnlineUsers)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    db.tab_OnlineUsers.Add(tab_OnlineUsers.OnlineUsers);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch(DbEntityValidationException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }

            }

            return View(tab_OnlineUsers);
        }

        // GET: OnlineUsers/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var RolesViewmode = new RolesViewMode
            {
                OnlineUsers = db.tab_OnlineUsers.Include(i => i.tab_OnlineRoles).First(i => i.Id == id),
            };
            if (RolesViewmode.OnlineUsers == null)
                return HttpNotFound();

            var allrolles = db.tab_OnlineRoles.ToList();
            RolesViewmode.AllRolesnames = allrolles.Select(o => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = o.Name,
                Value = o.Id.ToString()
            });

            tab_OnlineUsers tab_OnlineUsers = db.tab_OnlineUsers.Find(id);
            if (tab_OnlineUsers == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(RolesViewmode);
        }

        // POST: OnlineUsers/Edit/5
        // Aktivieren Sie zum Schutz vor übermäßigem Senden von Angriffen die spezifischen Eigenschaften, mit denen eine Bindung erfolgen soll. Weitere Informationen 
        // finden Sie unter http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Email,EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEndDateUtc,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount,UserName")] tab_OnlineUsers tab_OnlineUsers)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(tab_OnlineUsers).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(tab_OnlineUsers);
        }
```

Then finally the create view:

```
@model UserMangment.ViewModel.RolesViewMode

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>tab_OnlineUsers</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OnlineUsers.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.EmailConfirmed, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.EmailConfirmed)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.EmailConfirmed, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.PasswordHash, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.PasswordHash, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.PasswordHash, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.SecurityStamp, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.SecurityStamp, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.SecurityStamp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.PhoneNumberConfirmed, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.PhoneNumberConfirmed, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.TwoFactorEnabled, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.TwoFactorEnabled)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.TwoFactorEnabled, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.LockoutEndDateUtc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.LockoutEndDateUtc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.LockoutEndDateUtc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.LockoutEnabled, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.LockoutEnabled)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.LockoutEnabled, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.AccessFailedCount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.AccessFailedCount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.AccessFailedCount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.OnlineUsers.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AllRolesnames, "Roles Name", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedRoleTags, Model.AllRolesnames)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>


}
```

So this code Success to bring the list,however there is an error to save this information into my database.

Comment: Why this insignificant revision? The only thing that would significantly improve your question is elaborating on "there is an error".

Answer (score 1):

Let me just explore to you one technique to over come many to many relation issue.
When ever you face many to many relation in database you should make a lookup table for both tables in database Like:

**If you have  tables for roles and users (In case more then one roles assign to user) so you should make a lookup table for this work where you save RoleId and UserId (Id,RoleId,UserId etc whatever fields you want to add)..**

And whenever role is assign to user you should make a entry in that table.

There may be more possible solution for that but this what I am doing whenever I face many to many relation ship issue..

Thanks,

Hopefully this will help ...

Comment: if you have already work with entity frame work you will see that after calling the tables in your code so the lookup table will disappear and you will have a many to many relation

Comment: Sorry may be you got me wrong I said that their should be third table which contains RoleId and UserId as foreign keys. What actually happen after that is the relation between roles and users will break to **one to many between role and lookuptable** and to  **one to many between user and lookuptable**. Its worked me in EF I am doing this every time i face many to many relation .
May be it help you Bilal

Comment: Thanks but as i have already say there is here no brak up table even when you make this one to many table in the middle after call it with entity it will disappear

Comment: No worries but its strange how can table or entity disappears ...its totally weird ... did you remove relation of user and roles after creating lookuptable? asking just in case

Comment: it is totally normal and if you work with mvc before you will understand my question
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/702890/MVC-Entity-Framework-and-Many-to-Many-Relation

Comment: Hi , Just got it sorry for confusion Bilal . I was going for separate technique..
Just review your code can you just remove that part ** '[Bind(Include = "Id,Email,EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEndDateUtc,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount,UserName")]'** from POST mehtod or add the roles list in it too ...